# Does the "diagonal map" of the universal algebra of a Lie algebra depend on its association with the Lie algebra?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, lie-algebras

This is another naive question that popped up as I'm learning Lie theory.

Given a lie algebra $L$ over a field $k$ of characteristic 0, we can define its universal algebra $UL$ as a suitable quotient of the tensor algebra on the vector space $L$.

This universal algebra $UL$ carries a diagonal map $\Delta : UL\rightarrow UL\otimes_k UL$ which is induced from the usual diagonal map $L\rightarrow L\times L$ given by $x\mapsto (x,x)$, together with the isomorphism $UL\otimes_k UL\cong U(L\times L)$ (an isomorphism which is surprisingly nonobvious, as it seems to use in an essential way the Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt theorem).

In our setting over a field $k$ of characteristic 0, $L$ can be identified with the subspace of $UL$ on which $\Delta(x) = x\otimes 1 + 1\otimes x $.

In general, given any associative algebra $A$, and any map $\Delta : A\rightarrow A\otimes_k A$, the subspace of elements on which $\Delta(x) = x\otimes 1 + 1\otimes x$ is closed under the bracket $[x,y] = xy-yx$, and hence is a Lie subalgebra $L_\Delta$, though I don't see any reason for $A$ to be the universal algebra of $L_\Delta$.

My question is - in general, if $A$ is the universal algebra of some Lie algebra $L$, giving rise to a map $\Delta : A\rightarrow A\otimes_k A$ such that $L = L_\Delta$, then can there exist another $\Delta' : A\rightarrow A\otimes_k A$ such that $A$ is also the universal algebra of $L_{\Delta'}$ and such that $\Delta'$ is the usual diagonal map associated with the identification $A = UL_{\Delta'}$.

Secondly, is every associative algebra the universal algebra of some lie algebra?

EDIT: This second question is certainly false, thanks to Gro-Tsen's comment.

Comment: "Is every associative algebra the universal algebra of some lie algebra?" → Since a Lie algebra embeds in its universal enveloping algebra (henceafter "uea"), a commutative algebra could only be the uea of a zero Lie algebra; but the uea of a zero Lie algebra is a symmetric algebra, i.e., polynomial ring, and not every commutative algebra is a polynomial ring.  So, no.

Comment: What properties do you want your comultiplication map to have? And do you want to consider the antipode map at all?

Comment: @user44191 I suppose I want the comultiplication map to have any property that the diagonal map coming from a universal algebra has. (Edited now to reflect this). I'm a novice to this area so actually I'm not really familiar with its properties.

Comment: @oxeimon Many of those properties are closely tied to the multiplication and antipode maps on $U = UL_\Delta$. Do you want those properties as well, or are you looking only for properties inherent to the comultiplication map?

Comment: @user44191 I'm a little confused about your comment, probably because I don't know what properties you are referring to. I think I'm happy with the current state of my question. Perhaps you could give some examples in an answer?

Comment: You don't need PBW to argue that taking universal enveloping algebras sends direct sums to tensor products. You can argue via universal properties: direct sum and tensor product are both the "commutative coproduct," in that they are the universal thing admitting a map from two other things whose images commute (and the meaning of "commute" in Lie algebras and algebras is compatible).

Comment: Anyway, for the sake of having the word in this conversation: the structure $U(L)$ acquires from being a universal enveloping algebra is a Hopf algebra structure. The functor $L \mapsto U(L)$, regarded as taking values in Hopf algebras, is fully faithful. Your question is whether it reflects isomorphisms when regarded as taking values in algebras.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Re: your first comment. Ah! That's a great way to think about it. At first I found it strange, since of course the tensor algebra is noncommutative, but of course you're right. Indeed PBW is not necessarily.